# Error:java: Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, java-8

I'm pretty sure this is not a duplicated question because I've searched through other questions and tried their solutions and none of them applied.

Several months ago my harddrive malfunctioned with  bad sectors, so I had to do a superficial repair using windows' tool.

Now several months later I opened up my old android studio project, I find that the "make apk" option was completely gone, so I uninstalled both latest verions of Android studio and JDK. **the JDK was installed under c:\program files\java folder.**

The "make apk" option isn't exactly back, and I'm not able to rebuild my project, stuck with these errors and hints:

Information:Using javac 1.8.0_112-release to compile java sources

Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'Application'

Information:6/28/2017 10:54 AM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0

warnings in 1s 367ms

Error:java: Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

The thing is, I suspect I did not properly set up the classpath at all, but I don't really know if that is the case, anyway, I'm here asking for help.

Can you please help me? Cheers.

Comment: Maybe JDK language jars were removed from the classpath. Reapply the JSDK home path.

Comment: Hello, how do I do that? I found JDK home path, but not JSDK home path, assuming it's the same thing, I tried copying the path then paste it back (the exact same thing) again and click "apply", nothing happened, problem remains.

Comment: Goto: File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs Re-apply the JSDK home path.

Comment: ">Re-apply the JSDK home path"@sree how? There is not a button called "reapply", so I assume you meant what I did in my last reply?